# vue js - parsing data from clipbord (excel)

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, parsing, clipboard

I'm trying to parse data that the user paste from an excel file. y code look like this :

```
onPastingContacts(e) {
  const pastedData = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  const allPastedFields = pastedData.split('\n').filter(el => el !== '');
  allPastedFields.forEach(el => {
    const field = el.split('\t');
    let element = {
      'field1': field[0]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field2': field[1]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field3': field[2]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field4': field[3]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field5': field[4]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field6': field[5]?.replace(/\r/g, '')
    };
    Object.keys(element).forEach((key) => (element[key] == null) && delete element[key]); // remove empty fields from object
    Data.push(element)
  });
  return {Data}
},
```

And it works well in general, The problem is if the file contains text with '\n' or '\t'
it parses it as if it were a new line in the file (or if it \t a new cell).

for example, if I'm trying to paste this file :

[image]

if I print the pasted data its look like this :

`523961234    "This is an example with new line "`

and if I print the Data array its look like this :

```
[{field1: '523961234', field2: 'This is an example'},
{field1: 'with new line '}]
```

And I need that this will be the result:

```
[{field1: '523961234', field2: 'This is an example \n with new line '}]
```

I know why it's append , does anyone have an idea how I can parse in a way that its work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split by '\r\n'.
and this work for me.
the new lines inside the cell were just \n .
this is my code :

```
onPastingContacts(e) {
  const pastedData = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  const allPastedFields = pastedData.split('\r\n').filter(el => el !== '');
  allPastedFields.forEach(el => {
    const field = el.split('\t');
    let element = {
      'field1': field[0]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field2': field[1]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field3': field[2]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field4': field[3]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field5': field[4]?.replace(/\r/g, ''),
      'field6': field[5]?.replace(/\r/g, '')
    };
    Object.keys(element).forEach((key) => (element[key] == null) && delete element[key]); // remove empty fields from object
    Data.push(element)
  });
  return {Data}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is remove the new lines everywhere where in-between quotation marks. You can use this RegEx `/\n+(?=(?:(?!\"|\").)*\")/gs` to find these new lines.
So line

```
onPastingContacts(e) {
  const pastedData = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  const regEx = /\n+(?=(?:(?!\"|\").)*\")/gs;
  const allPastedFields = pastedData.replaceAll(regEx, " ").split('\n').filter(el => el !== '');
  // Rest of your code here.
}
```

Note: If you need to preserve the newLines in each field you can replace the newLines with a placeholder - Example `.replaceAll(regEx,'{NEW_LINE}')`. Then when you parse the field you can replace it with a new line - Example `.replaceAll('{NEW_LINE}', '\n')`.

Original RegEx inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573958/6024735).

Comment: It did not work if I have multiple lines in the excel file.

Comment: but i use your idea of the placeholder  -Thank you!!!

Comment: @Elijah Please submit your code/idea as an answer, so if someone else has the same issue it will be more relative than mine, or provide an Excel snippet, so I can change my implementation and have a correct answer.